# Como leer codigo barra camara android

Tags: c#

Buenas tarde, necesito saber como puedo leer un codigo de barra con la camara de android con visual studio.

Comment: Esta pregunta es un poco amplia. ¿Lo estás haciendo de manera nativa o usando algún plugin?¿Qué has probado?¿Dónde encuentras fallos? En la propia página de MSDN tienes un tutorial (tristemente no traducido) donde explican [cómo crear un scanner de códigos de barras](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn792060(v=winembedded.81).aspx)

Comment: cuando dices andriod en c# estas usando apachec cordova o Xamarin ? es un codigo de barra o es un QR ?

Comment: He usado ZXing creo que es lo que comunmente se usa para estos casos, en el caso de Android, ahora la versión de C# existe también.

Answer (score 3):

Yo he usado principalmente en [Java ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) pero existe la versión para C# que es:

https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

> **ZXing** : Sirve para generar y decodificar codigos de barrra como QR Code, PDF
>   417, EAN, UPC, Aztec, Data Matrix, Codabar dentro de imagenes.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo* para Android usando ZXing **["Android: Crea un lector de Código de Barra"](http://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162)**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

otros recursos:

**[Leer y generar códigos con ZXing (Java)](http://zomwi.blogspot.mx/2012/09/zxing.html)**

**[Leer códigos de barras (Windows Phone)](https://javiersuarezruiz.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/windows-phone-leer-codigos-de-barras/)**